# Unix - Increment the Count of 6 variables in a document

Tags: unix, increment

Unix - I have a file called "iclassroster" which has the following data:

Last Name  :  First Name  : Student ID  :  Program & Plan  :  Academic Level  :  ASURITE  :  Email

Alvarado  :  Anthony  : 1209480997  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  aalvar33  :  aalvar33@asu.edu

Alvarez  :  Gibran  : 1201390350  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  galvare2  :  galvare2@asu.edu

Angus  :  Glen  : 1000746988  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  gangus  :  gangus@asu.edu

Ashby  :  Cole  : 1207146326  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  cashby  :  cashby@asu.edu

Bailey  :  Allan  : 1000548822  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  asu41981  :  asu41981@asu.edu

Barron  :  Rudy  : 1208428789  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  rrbarron  :  rrbarron@asu.edu

Box  :  Jeffrey  : 1208427112  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Post-Bacc Undergraduate  :  jabox1  :  jabox1@asu.edu

Burden  :  Nicholas  : 1206996878  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  nbburden  :  nbburden@asu.edu

Camiliere  :  Kurtis  : 1200663364  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  kcamilie  :  kcamilie@asu.edu

Camp  :  Michael  : 1000830925  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  mcamp1  :  mcamp1@asu.edu

Carleton  :  Robert  : 1000727027  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  rcarleto  :  rcarleto@asu.edu

Cartwright  :  Dustin  : 1001460822  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Tech Entrepreneurship & Mgmt  :  Senior  :  dbcartwr  :  dbcartwr@asu.edu

Cook  :  John  : 1201860560  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Senior  :  jrcook7  :  jrcook7@asu.edu

Debiasio  :  Thomas  : 1207331615  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Software Engineering  :  Post-Bacc Undergraduate  :  tdebiasi  :  tdebiasi@asu.edu

Dixon  :  Jason  : 1208487705  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Software Engineering  :  Junior  :  jadixon5  :  jadixon5@asu.edu

Fernandez  :  Jose  : 1207627963  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Post-Bacc Undergraduate  :  jlferna4  :  jlferna4@asu.edu

Hale  :  Hunter  : 1207103803  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  hehale  :  hehale@asu.edu

Heisey  :  Thane  : 1207033252  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  theisey  :  theisey@asu.edu

Hoyle  :  Jeremy  : 1000527662  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  jhoyle  :  jhoyle@asu.edu

Jardine  :  Parker  : 1201654029  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Post-Bacc Undergraduate  :  pjardine  :  pjardine@asu.edu

Johnson  :  Joshua  : 1000745321  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  jrjohnso  :  jrjohnso@asu.edu

Kone  :  Chinmingnon  : 1207997618  :  Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information Technology  :  Junior  :  cdkone  :  cdkone@asu.edu

I need to create an If Else awk script to count the following:
How many times does Information Technology occur?
How many Freshmen there are?
How many Sophmore  there are?
How many Juniors there are?
How many Seniors there are? 
How many Post-Bacc Undergrads there are?
and output this info to the screen.

So far I only have this and needs some help tooling my script to work for all the questions one after the other in an If elseif else structure.  Please help I know it needs alot of work, but I have been tinkering with it for 2 days now.  the letters were my count variables.

```
while read -r iclassroster _; do

A=0
IT="Information"
B=0
FR="Freshman"
C=0
JU="Junior"
D=0
SO="Sophmore"
E=0
SE="Senior"
F=0
PBU="Post"


if  [ "Information" = "$iclassroster" ]; then
    ((A++)) | echo $A
fi
done
```

Comment: format your question properly. its too messy to be useful for other to answer.

Comment: Sorry.  Its the first question I have ever posted on here.

Comment: I hope that that is better so that the data does not look like each record is running into each other.